# Header Section of IBM MQ Message Contains Garbled Characters After Implementing OpenTelemetry (OTEL) for Tracing

Tags: ibm-mq, trace, open-telemetry, spring-boot-3, open-telemetry-java

I recently replaced DataDog with OpenTelemetry in a Spring Boot application. Upon inspecting the logs and traces, no issues were identified. However, a specific functionality in the application involves publishing messages to IBM MQ. While using DataDog, we encountered no problems, but since migrating to OpenTelemetry, IBM MQ messages now contain special characters. I am seeking guidance on disabling trace propagation to MQ. How can I deactivate OTEL propagation or TraceParent specifically for the JMS queue? I believe this modification could potentially resolve the issue. Are there any alternative suggestions for resolving this matter?

Comment: Can you check if DataDog agent and libraries are completely disabled? We have found while sending data to SigNoz via OTel, that if both DataDog and Otel are installed it gives weird issues sometimes

Comment: Yes, everything related to DataDog I have cleanedup

Answer (score 0):

You can [disable](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/docs/supported-libraries.md) the "JMS" or "Spring JMS" module.

In addition, you can create a [bug report](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/issues) with detailed information what is wrong exactly.